# Sails.js hide association in response

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a model with `one-to-many` association in sails.js:

```
USER:

  attributes: {
      name: {
          type: "string",
          required: true,
      },
      photos: {
          collection: "Photo",
          via: "user"
      }
  },
```

and

```
PHOTO:

  attributes: {
      url: {
          type: "string",
          required: true
      },
      user: {
          model: "user"
      }
  }
```

But right now, my problem is, that when I'm showing all users by simply navigating to `http://localhost:1337/user` it is showing user model with all photos assiciated to id and I would like to have different route for getting photos.

Is it possible to hide it, or I need to remove it from model and then search for photos with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in [sails.config.blueprints](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints) with the populate property.

I never tested it, but try to add a `populate` property to `false` in [config/blueprints.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/blueprints-js)

Comment: Can I configure it per model? Or it's globally only?

Comment: You should be able to override the blueprint configuration [per controller](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) #/disabling-blueprints-on-a-per-controller-basis